# Chrome Custom Tabs - Intent not being triggered (Android)

Tags: android, android-intent, paypal, redirect, chrome-custom-tabs

I am working on implementing PayPal into my current Android app, and I have been advised to use Chrome Custom Tabs, but I cannot seem to get the Intent to be triggered.

I believe I have set the Intent up correctly in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.rhiannon.chromecustomtabs">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".CompletePayPalPaymentActivity">
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:scheme="Test"
                android:host="com.Test.TestApp.PayPalReturn"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I am able to successfully launch the Google Chrome Tabs in my Fragment class (Where I have got 2 buttons:

- A button that will launch www.google.co.uk in a Chrome Custom Tab
- A button that launches my custom webpage (hosted on localhost) that will throw the redirects when the user clicks a button/link

Please see below the code for this Fragment:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements CustomTabsSceneHelper.ConnectionCallback {

    public enum CustomTabsAction {
        GOOGLE ("Open Google", "http://google.co.uk"),
        REDIRECT ("Open Redirect", "http://{mylocalhost_ip}/~Rhiannon/example1/test.html");

        private final String mActionDescription;
        private final String mActionUrl;

        CustomTabsAction (
                final String actionDescription,
                final String actionUrl) {

            mActionDescription = actionDescription;
            mActionUrl = actionUrl;
        }

        public String actionDescription () {
            return mActionDescription;
        }

        public String actionUrl () {
            return mActionUrl;
        }
    }

    private CustomTabsSceneHelper mCustomTabsSceneHelper;
    private CustomTabsAction mCurrentAction;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mCustomTabsSceneHelper = new CustomTabsSceneHelper();
        mCustomTabsSceneHelper.setConnectionCallback(this);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        Button buttonGoogle = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_google);
        buttonGoogle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                open(CustomTabsAction.GOOGLE);
            }
        });

        Button buttonRedirect = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_redirect);
        buttonRedirect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                open(CustomTabsAction.REDIRECT);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    private void open(CustomTabsAction action) {
        final Activity scene = getActivity ();
        mCurrentAction = action;

        CustomTabsSceneHelper.openCustomTab(
                scene,
                getCustomTabIntent(scene, mCustomTabsSceneHelper.occupySession()).build(),
                Uri.parse(action.actionUrl())
        );
    }

    public static CustomTabsIntent.Builder getCustomTabIntent(
            @NonNull Context context,
            @Nullable CustomTabsSession session) {

        // Construct our intent via builder
        final CustomTabsIntent.Builder intentBuilder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder (session);
        // Toolbar color
        intentBuilder.setToolbarColor(Color.GREEN);
        // Show title
        intentBuilder.setShowTitle(true);
        // Allow hiding for toolbar
        intentBuilder.enableUrlBarHiding();

        return intentBuilder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCustomTabsConnected() {
        Log.i("MainFragment", "Custom Tabs > CONNECTED");
        if(mCurrentAction != null){
            mCustomTabsSceneHelper.mayLaunchUrl(Uri.parse(mCurrentAction.actionUrl()), null, null);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCustomTabsDisconnected() {
        Log.i("MainFragment", "Custom Tabs > DISCONNECTED");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mCustomTabsSceneHelper.bindCustomTabsService(getActivity());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        mCustomTabsSceneHelper.unbindCustomTabsService(getActivity());
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mCustomTabsSceneHelper.setConnectionCallback(null);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

I then have my custom webpage:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PayPal Test Redirect</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function RedirectSuccess(){
            window.location="Test://com.Test.TestApp.PayPalReturn://return";
        }

        function RedirectCancel(){
            window.location="Test://com.Test.TestApp.PayPalReturn://cancel";
        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="Test://com.Test.TestApp.PayPalReturn://return">Success</a>
<a href="Test://com.Test.TestApp.PayPalReturn://cancel">Cancel</a>

<input type="button" onclick="RedirectSuccess();" name="ok" value="Success"  />
<input type="button" onclick="RedirectCancel();" name="ok" value="Cancel"  />
</body>
</html>
```

I would expect that when the user clicks on one of the links/buttons on the webpage in the Chrome Custom Tab that the user would be redirected back to the application, but I cannot seem to get this functionality to work.

```
public class CompletePayPalPaymentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_complete_paypal);

        List<String> params = getIntent().getData().getPathSegments();
        if(params.get(0).equals("return")){
            Log.i("CompletePP", "PayPal Payment Success");
        }else{
            Log.i("CompletePP", "PayPal Payment Cancelled");
        }
    }
}
```

Any help at all, would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For anyone else who's trying to use `http://localhost:8200` as the `redirectUrl` for their authorizations... you can't use `localhost` at all with `Chrome Custom Tabs`... you need to define your own custom url scheme. You may need to have your backend developer include this change on their end, if you're just the Android dev.

Answer (score 9):

I think your scheme and host is mixed up. Custom scheme URIs don't have hosts! So try this instead:

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```
    <activity android:name=".CompletePayPalPaymentActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="com.Test.TestApp.PayPalReturn"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Then the link your HTML would be:

```
<a href="com.Test.TestApp.PayPalReturn:/cancel">Cancel</a>
```

For a working example, checkout [AppAuth for Android](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android), it shows a Chrome Custom Tab being used to perform an OAuth flow (to Google's OAuth servers), *including* parsing data from a return intent. Here's the [AndroidManifest.xml](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android/blob/48aaa35/app/AndroidManifest.xml#L33) from that demo.